# Does SWT's virtual tables release TableItems

Tags: java, memory, swt

In the context of displaying databases rows in an SWT VIRTUAL `Table` I am wondering if created `TableItem`s are ever released by SWT in order for them to be garbage collected ?

Using virtual table allows us not to load the full model into memory by asking on the fly data to the database each time SWT needs it (through the SWT.setData listener). I am now wondering if an out of memory error can occur if the user scrolls for a very long time in a big table and thus all TableItem that have been displayed are somewhere in memory ?

Thanks in advance

Manu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several investigations I confirm that SWT never releases the created TableItem. But, this is not a problem because of the Virtual style and SWT's power, a small amount of such items is created even if the user performs quick scrolling over all the table.